# Where are the calculated fields from Odoo stored in the sql server when stored is set to true

Tags: sql, sql-server, field, store, odoo-9

If I create a new field on a model, making it a calculated or related field, and set the store parameter to be true. When I look on the sql server using pg admin, on the table itself, i can't fiend the field. I think this would be logic if the data entered wouldn't be stored, but calculated each time it was shown on a view (from, tree, ...).

Example in the POS orderline the field tax_ids is a calculated / related field. The tax_id is stored, because if I change the id on product level, it doesn't affect the order line, when consulting it after changing the tax id. So this data is stored. But when I try to find the field in the pos_order_line model on the sql server it doesn't show on the pos orderline. In odoo, settings models, it does show on the pos_order_line model. So where does odoo store the data?